# Product property

Tags: universal-property

What is the name of the following property of two equal products?

> If $ab = cd$, then $a(b-d)=(c-a)d$

Comment: I don't suppose this has a name.  There are many, many algebraic identities. Most of them lack names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a(b-d)=(c-a)d \iff ab-ad=cd-ad \iff ab=cd$.

The reason ist the distributive property of addition and multiplication in $ \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the multilinearity of the determinant (substracting the first column from the second one does not change the determinant), i.e.,
$$
ab-cd=\det \begin{pmatrix} a & c \cr d & b \end{pmatrix}=\det 
\begin{pmatrix} a & c-a \cr d & b-d \end{pmatrix}=a(b-d)-(c-a)d.
$$